# What's the reward for completing missions?

Tags: ingress

It's pretty unclear what's granted for completing missions.  Even the web doesn't agree on the answer:

- [This Reddit's Q/A](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/2ia8m6/you_get_ap_to_do_a_mission/) says there's no AP
- [This Decode Ingress' page](http://decodeingress.me/2012/11/28/who-would-love-more-missions/) talks about missions rewarding AP
- [The Verge has a post](http://www.theverge.com/2014/9/25/6840157/google-ingress-scavenger-hunt-missions-launch) mentionning missions rewarding AP as well

The only thing they all agree on is the custom badge earned at the end of each mission.

So: do you earn APs for completing missions ?  If you do, is it worth it ?

Comment: The second link (Decode Ingress) has mission ideas, but isn't relevant to "missions" as they're currently implemented -- it dates from 2012 :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get a mission badge, and there's also a medal called SpecOps that's given after completing unique missions. Levels are:

- bronze: 5
- silver: 25
- gold: 100
- platinum: 200
- onyx: 500

I've not seen any mission give AP on completion.

*Update in july*

I've done quite a few missions recently, and they indeed gave AP, 125 each. I'm still not sure if it's only a few missions, or they all give.

Answer (score 4):

A badge is given as well as 125AP. I assume that one could consider the items gathered in the hack to be reward. Further of the portal is owned by the enemy a takedown and turning grants you AP. So really it's what you do at these portals during a mission that would bring the outcome

Answer (score 4):

As a traveler and ingress enthusiast, I've found the missions to serve best as "location history". Typically you only do missions (particularly banners and mosaics) when you are in the area for an extended time and want a lasting memory of it on ingress. This gives depth to each agent as you can get a sense of their history without knowing exact details.